# Serialize a .net Object directly to a NetworkStream using Json.net

Tags: .net, json, serialization, json.net, networkstream

Is there any way to have Json.net serialize an object directly to a NetworkStream?

In other words, have Json.net send the serialized result to the network as it serializes the object (in a streaming fashion).

I would like to avoid having to serialize the object to memory and then send it via the NetworkStream.

Any thoughts?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `TextWriter` on top of a `NetworkStream`, and serialize to the `TextWriter`; or you can create a `JsonTextWriter` on top of a `TextWriter` and serialize to that.

You don't need to serialize to, say, a temporary string or byte array first.